# convergent of series problem

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

So I have this question which I do not understand:

The series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n| $ is convergent.

The series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n $ is convergent, but the series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |b_n| $ is not convergent.

So which one of the following is **not always** true:

1. You can change the order of the sequence so that $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n + b_n) $ so it will convergent to $0$
2. You can change the order of the sequence so that $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n b_n) $ so it will convergent to $0$
3. Each brackets you will put on  $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n b_n) $ will be convergent
4. Each brackets you will put on  $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n + b_n) $ will be convergent

Could someone give me a counterexample for this question ?

I tried to solve that but I did not make it.

Comment: Are you **completely sure** you meant $\,|\sum a_n|\;$ and *not* $\;\sum |a_n|\;$ , and the same for $\,b_n\;$ ? This looks odd as it is...

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank u !!

Comment: In the first two questions, you say we can change the order of the sequence but there are two sequences here $(a_n)_n$ and $(b_n)_n$...

Comment: @user37238 I ment we can change the order of the sequence  $(a_n + b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$

Comment: Have you looked at the [Riemann series theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_rearrangement_theorem) ?

Answer (score 1):

We know

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\;,\;\;\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|\;,\;\;\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n\;\;\text{are convergent}\;,\;\;\sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n|\;\;\text{is divergent}$$

From here and from arithmetic of limits (of series), we get at once that (1) is  always true since this is a conditionally convergente series (why?) and we apply Riemann's Theorem...and this already gives you the answer: (4) is not always true.

Comment: Thank u !! I just remember the theorem. but I have another question,from all the information we have how can u conclude that $ \ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n + b_n| \ \ $ is divergent ? I know that  $ \ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n + b_n| \ \leq  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n| + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|b_n| \ $ that equals to something that convergent and something else that is divergent, so how ?

Comment: Better use $\;|a_n+b_n|\ge |a_n|-|b_n|\;$ and you get divergence by the comparison test...

Comment: Thank u !! you are right !!